# The function pg_query() gives an error in php

Tags: php, postgresql

I want to insert data in pgsql database. But the function `pg_query()` gives an error when I want to insert data. The error is:

```
Warning: pg_query() [function.pg-query]: Query failed: ERROR: array value must start with "{" or dimension information LINE 1: INSERT INTO demo_insert(id, name) VALUES ('1234', 'abcd') ^ in C:\wamp\www\NetBeansProjects\PhpProject1\index1.php on line 19
```

My code is as follows:

```
<?php   

    require_once "connection.php"; 
   //page for connection to the database

    pg_set_client_encoding($dbconn, "UNICODE"); 
    //$dbconn is the variable where pg_connect() is executed

    $id="1234";

    $name="abcd";

    $query = "INSERT INTO demo_insert(id, name) VALUES ('$id', '$name')";  
    $result = pg_query($dbconn, $query);

    if($result)
    {
        echo "1 row is inserted";
    }
?>
```

Can you please tell me the solution of this error?

Comment: what type is `id` column?

Comment: Can you please bring the description of `demo_insert` table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like one of your columns is an array type, not a "normal" type. Could you show us your table definitions?

Offtopic: When using input parameters, you have to do something to avoid SQL injection. The easiest solution is using pg_query_params() instead of pg_query():

```
<?php
    $id="1234";

    $name="abcd";
    // placeholders $1 and $2:
    $query = "INSERT INTO demo_insert(id, name) VALUES ($1, $2)"; 
    // array with your content:
    $result = pg_query_params($dbconn, $query, array($id, $name)); 
?>
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. Frank sir for you response. But it also gives the same error. 
Warning: pg_query_params() [function.pg-query-params]: Query failed: ERROR: array value must start with "{" or dimension information in C:\wamp\www\NetBeansProjects\PhpProject1\index1.php on line 21.........

Comment: My table definition is:   CREATE TABLE demo_insert
(
  id character varying(10)[],
  name character varying(50)[]
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE demo_insert
  OWNER TO postgres;

Comment: Thank you very much to all of you. Actually. my data types are of array type. so, I got the error. After correcting it, I got the result...

Comment: character varying(10)[]: [] means you want an array, not a "normal" datatype. Drop the table and create a new one without the [ and ]. And why do you want a VARCHAR for a numeric id? Use an integer.